# How can I process FHIR data in Cloudera CDP environment?

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-nifi, hl7-fhir, cloudera-cdp

I'm developing a NiFi pipeline in CDP to process FHIR data that are stored in an external DB. Is there any specific tool that I can use in Apache NiFi to read and manipulate FHIR data? Or, as alternative, for Apache Spark? Until now I didn't find anything interesting.